# Save well-formed XML from PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I create an XmlDocument like this:

```
$doc = New-Object xml
```

Then, after filling it with nodes, I save it:

```
$doc.Save($fileName)
```

The problem is that it does not add the XML declaration to the beginning of the document, resulting in malformed document. In other words, it only saves a fragment. How can I add a correct XML declaration to it?

Comment: FYI the lack of an XML declaration doesn't make an XML file malformed as it is not a required element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) class to format the output. Here is a sample, though you may want to evolve it for any specific needs you have beyond adding the header:

```
$doc = [xml]"<html>Value</html>"
$sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter($sb)
$writer = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($sw)
$writer.Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
$doc.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
$sw.Dispose()
```

Later, by calling the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1063zt.aspx) method on the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) object, you can see the following output:

```
PS C:\> $sb.ToString()
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<html>Value</html>
```

Comment: I ran into an issue with this if the html tag had a transitional doctype. The html could not be parsed into a valid xml document.

Comment: While this approach works, using the integrated XML methods in powershell is an overall better solution.

Answer (score 16):

Or you can use the `CreateXmlDeclaration` method on `XmlDocument` e.g.:

```
$doc = new-object xml
$decl = $doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", $null, $null)
$rootNode = $doc.CreateElement("root");
$doc.InsertBefore($decl, $doc.DocumentElement)
$doc.AppendChild($rootNode);
$doc.Save("C:\temp\test.xml")
```

Comment: you can add $decl with $doc.AppendChild as well